# Typescript - components missing typed props are not throwing error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I created a type for my component and for some reason it's not throwing errors when I use it in the wild without the *required* types. Am I missing something here? I feel like I have everything.

```
type MapProps = {
  progress: number;
  format: string;
  summary: string;
};

const MapElement = ({ progress, format, summary }: MapProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Content>
      <VerticalBar />
      <Icon />
      <TextWrapper>
        <Text>
          <P3 bold>
            {progress} - {format}
          </P3>
          <P3 secondary>{summary}</P3>
        </Text>
      </TextWrapper>
    </Content>
  );
};
```

```
const LanguageModule = () => {
  ...
  return (
    ...
      <ModuleMap>
          <MapElement progress={5} />     <--- No type errors are appearing
          <MapElement />                  <--- No type errors are appearing
      </ModuleMap>
    ...
  );
};
```

Comment: How are you checking for errors? Have you tried making another deliberate mistake (`const x: number = true`) and checking if it shows an error? I'm seeing a type error on your code in my IDE.

Comment: Hm... very strange. Yeah i've been making deliberate errors and nothing is getting picked up or flagged.

Comment: @g2jose my other typed components are still working as well

Comment: I have this file at `/components/_molecules/MapElement.tsx`

Comment: Does putting this same code in a file that you know flags type errors help?

Comment: What sort of errors are you looking for? runtime errors? TS will best-effort compile code with type errors, and NextJS will (as far as I know, without extra config) ignore type errors in dev.

Comment: @TylerSebastian in this case i'm looking for it to say i'm missing props that are required in my component via it's types. What confusing me is why this component is mysteriously not acting the same way all the others are in regards to typescript. I've written all the other components the same way and yet TS is picking it up when i dont pass in required props.

Comment: @g2jose i havent tried that yet, I moved the file around but not that. I'll try that attempt tomorrow morning.

Comment: Well, I figured it out ... I thought the issue was with the component itself but the page I was calling it in was a `.jsx` file. Thanks for the help :sad: